# Test Cases in nodejs with mocha, chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, testcase

Currently, I have created a test for two functions using `mocha` and `chai`.

They should response differently according to different params from `HTTP POST/GET` request.

However, I wonder what is the best practice to check 3 test cases which I expect they will have the same input.

For example,

```
describe('Function A', function() {

it('should retrun 404 when receipt ID is invalid', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/generateSales/')
        .send(validParams1)
        .end(function(err, res){
            res.should.have.status(404);
            done();
        });
});

it('should retrun 404 when receipt ID is invalid', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/generateSales/')
        .send(validParams2)
        .end(function(err, res){
            res.should.have.status(404);
            done();
        });
});

it('should retrun 404 when receipt ID is invalid', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/generateSales/')
        .send(validParams3)
        .end(function(err, res){
            res.should.have.status(404);
            done();
        });
});


});
```

What is the correct way to test all params(validParams1,2,3) in a single `it` block? (as I expect they have the same response)

Answer (score 0):

Due to asynchronous matters, you should not call for loop inside the `it` block.

I found a alternative solution instead, using `it-each` module

The following link shows how to deal with asynchronous test loops with mocha when you want to use 20 APIs or 20 test cases within an `it` block

https://whitfin.io/asynchronous-test-loops-with-mocha/

Answer (score 0):

https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

```js
describe('Function A', function() {
  let paramSets = [
    validParams1,
    validParams2,
    validParams3
  ]
  paramSets.forEach((paramSet)=>{
    // call it multiple times.
    it('should return 404 when receipt ID is invalid', function(done) {
      // this is technically a different function each time
      chai.request(server)
        .post('/generateSales/')
        .send(paramSet) // this is different for each function/test
        .end(function(err, res){
          res.should.have.status(404);
          done();
        });
    });
    // never call assert here.
    // The function passed to 'it' runs as the test.
    // The function passed to 'describe' runs first, and sets up all the tests.
  });
});
```